# Stacked objects fading but shadow stays

Tags: animation, materials, camera, shadows

I want to make a stack of objects fade away but in my stack of five rectangles fading goes well but after the third fade, the shadow of the faded objects doesn't go away. How can I make the shadows fade too?

Here's visualisation of my problem ->[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was animating the alpha channel in the materials property but the shadow doesn't fade. To fix that I had to animate the visibility properties on each element in -> Object Properties > Visibility.